# Issue while drawing an haplotype network using {pegas}

Tags: r, dna-sequence, phylogeny, genetics

I am trying to produce a haplotype network using pegas. I managed to do the basic network, but when I try to add slices of different color to each "pie" I can't seem to move forward.

I will replicate my error using the the woodmouse dataset:

```
data(woodmouse)
x <- woodmouse[sample(15, size = 110, replace = TRUE), ]
h <- haplotype(x)
net <- haploNet(h)
plot(net, size=attr(net, "freq"), scale.ratio = 2, cex = 0.8)

ind.hap<-with(
  stack(setNames(attr(h, "index"), rownames(h))), 
  table(hap=ind, pop=rownames(x)[values])
)
```

With the above code I manage to plot the network no problem, but when I try to execute the last four lines of code I get the following error:

```
ind.hap<-with(
  stack(setNames(attr(h, "index"), rownames(h))), 
  table(hap=ind, pop=rownames(x)[values])
)

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘raster’ for signature ‘"integer"’
```

Any suggestion on what might be the problem?

Comment: That did it, thanks MrFlick. I guess there was a conflict with other packages, likely raster. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message sounds like it's coming from the `stack()` function from the `raster` package rather than the base `stack()` function. Packages can both define functions with the same name; R will find the one from the most recently loaded package. To use the version from `utils`, you can prefix it with the namespace and `::`. For example

```
utils::stack(setNames(attr(h, "index"), rownames(h)))
```

That should solve the problem.